# INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE col = col

Tags: mysql, sql

Please can someone help me, I have a table of users and another table with users and date time (this is a log file and multiple dates exist per user). I need to take the most recent date from the log table and insert it into the first table next to the same user.

This is what I have but its not working:

```
INSERT INTO tb1 n (DT) 
SELECT w.DT 
FROM tb2 w
WHERE w.User = n.User
ORDER BY w.DT DESC
limit 1
```

Comment: "*insert it into the first table*" does not make any sense. Neither does "*next to the same user*"

Comment: do you really want to INSERT into the users table? or update would be fine? because I think you don't want to have duplicate users in your first (users) table. just want to update the max_date column of that table. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to use `INSERT` statement here since there are already records present on your table. But instead `UPDATE` it with `JOIN`

```
UPDATE  tb1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user, MAX(DT) maxDT
            FROM    tb2
            GROUP by user
        ) b ON a.user = b.user
SET     a.DT = b.maxDT
```